# PostgreSQL - dangerous built-in functions to avoid for dynamic queries?

Tags: postgresql, dynamic-sql

In our software product, we want to add a feature that allows advanced users to define their own database views by entering any select statement they want, which will then be used in a "create view" statement.

While this is arguably dangerous in and by itself, are there any PostgreSQL functions that add dangers greater than "seeing everything in the database" and "overstraining the database by joining too many tables"?

I think of functions that would allow the execution of DDL statemtents, accessing the file system, executing commands on OS level etc.

Comment: Just make sure that those users only have SELECT privileges on the tables they need, then they can't really do much harm.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name except create a cartesian select that sets the server on fire ;-)

Comment: @Stu: that could be somewhat mitigated using a conservative `statement_timeout` for that user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions that are publicly available will be your least problem. All functions that can access the operating system are restricted to superusers and members of certain predefined roles like `pg_write_server_files` or `pg_execute_server_programs`.

Still, I think that this is a bad idea: anybody who can submit an SQL statement can easily launch a successful denial-of-service attack, either hogging the CPU or filling the disk with temporary files.